# How to add text to model

Tags: edit-mode

I want to add signs including text to my model.
I ADDed MESH > PLANE for the sign board resized and scaled and then ADDed TEXT changed font size then moved (Grab) both only the side of my model. THe model in Blender looks ok to me (but obviously wrong) but the exported extended glTF used in MSFS shows the boards but no text - see images. What is the correct way of adding a 'sign' to an object?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The easy way of adding it would be through textures. Did u try making a material -> adding texture?

Comment: What did u mean when you said "Added Text", did u mean the 2D Text mesh? If so, did u try adding some 3D height to it as a 2D mesh would overlap with the surface u r trying to put on

Comment: Thanks Suhas. When I added the 'plane' I applied a Material to it and chose a Base Color to it. Should it be done a different way?  I have only ever so far added an Image Texture to objects. What is the correct method when I only want it to be white?          I When I created the text for the sign I did it via ADD > TEXT object and then simply changed the font size and of course the actual text (from Text to Public etc).

Comment: If you use a text object with zero thickness, i.e. no extrusion to give it some height, and you have it sitting directly in the same location as the plane used as the sign background, then the intersecting geometry can cause strange artifacts or maybe even hide the text completely. So if you want a text object you need to give it some height - or place it a little bit in front of the sign (but that would actually make the text float in the air).

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That makes perfect sense. I have added Geometry > Extrude  (0.01) and will see what happens. What about the actual sign ( I created via Add > Mesh > Plane)? Should have I used Add > Mesh >Cube to give it some 'depth'? What is 'plane' normally used for? In MSFS the actual 'sign' is displayed with a strange texture even though I only left a Base Color on it?

Comment: What "plane" is normally used for? Well, many things... starting point for lots of meshes. Emitter of particles. Floor for rigid body simulations. Lots of things. You don't have to add depth to use it as a sign, a cube instead of a plane of course has more geometry (= more information to be calculated or stored), but it depends on how realistic you want to model something. If your sign is just a sheet of paper, than zero thickness is acceptable (although of course even paper has a thickness), but if it's a more "robust" sign made from e.g. wood, it's usually a lot thicker than paper.

Comment: However, if you're not zooming in too much you might get away with a completely thin sign. Then the question is, why use a Text object for the text? As long as you don't have some kind of billboard with replaceable letters, usually signs have the text printed or painted in thin layers of color on them, so an image texture with the words on it would be fine. You can even use one material with one image with all words on it and put them on different objects, as long as their UV maps fit the correct text areas they should display. For MSFS question: I'm sorry, I don't know anything about MSFS...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add Mesh -> Plane -> scale it in edit mode on y as needed
2. add solidify modifier + bevel modifier

[image]

3. add text -> under geometry: give text some extrude value

[image]

4. add materials to text + plane

[image]

Comment: Well I followed these instructions and even 'extruded' the text for the middle sign to 0.1 and so in Blender the text is easily seen protruding from the plane yet in MSFS it is still not seen. Strangely there also is a problem with the boat bumpers/fenders which have blue ends and easily seen in Blender as blue but are white in MSFS.  Any ideas. what to check/change?

Comment: Sorry, but what is MSFS?

Comment: Sorry  Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020

Comment: ok, i tested it. Looks like solidify modifier + bevel modifier must be applied so that gltf can export/import it. Please try this out and let me know whether this helped. I could successfully export/import my text with applied modifiers.

Comment: Thanks again for trying to work this out for me. Not sure what you mean by "applied" but if you mean that 'apply modifiers' in 'geometry must be ticked I already have it ticked. Should I be converting the text and plane to mesh?

Comment: Ok, please try this: just export your sign+text to gltf. Then start new blender file and import it. Does this work? If not, please provide your blend file. Then I will check it out.

Comment: I am now thinking that MSFS is causing the problem as during the compilation (of all my scenery glTFs) it displays the following -   Compiling glTF data for ..... (name of file)  then displays  Material for this name already exists Material.001 renaming to  Material.001x  it also displays the same message for Material.002 (renaming to Material.002x)    and also Material (renaming to Materialx).  I can't see all these materials in the materials panel in Blender.   Maybe I should delete the plane and text and start again.  Should the (default names) material be renamed?

Comment: Only if other materials have the same name and this seems to be the case here. But I don‘t know whether this causes the problem but I would rename it if I were you

Comment: I just had a break from this and thought of two possibilities but it is late and so will try it out tomorrow and report back.

Comment: I think I have found the reason why the signs don't display in MSFS even after making changes suggested above. I believe (yet to be confirmed) that Airport Design Editor is the culprit as I removed 2 of the signs, exported and built into my MSFS scenery and yet the three signs are still displayed and found old versions of the files in another folder which I know nothing about. I have placed a query on the Airport Design Editor forum to seek answers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126746/discussion-between-john-arnold-and-chris).